# How to connect Docker container to Docker Network when started in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2019

I have created an ASP.NET CORE api and added Docker support to the project (`sftt.app`). I also have a MongoDB instance in another container (`sftt.db`). In order to ease connecting the application to the Database, I use the name of the Database container in the connection string. This requires that both containers be connected to a Docker Network, which I have named `sftt-net`. When I start the container for `sftt.app` I would like to automatically connect to `sftt-net` as part of it's `docker run` just as I do with my database, however I can't find an option for doing this in Visual Studio.

I tried adding a command line argument `"commandLineArgs": "--network sftt-net"` in the `launchSettings.json` file, but that didn't work. (I also tried `connect sftt-net sftt.app`)

How can I add the api container to the Network on startup when it's launched from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11):

You can specify additional Docker arguments by editing the csproj file and adding the following:

```xml
<DockerfileRunArguments>arguments go here</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

An example of a csproj file edited to connect the Docker container to a network called `mongo_cluster` would look as follows

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>--network mongo_cluster</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.11.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```